# Setup Minecraft Forge to create mod in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gradle, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to make a mod in minecraft (1.12.x) in eclipse, but i'm having a lot of problems with it. Many I managed to solve them but this problem not:

*Unresolved dependency: net.minecraftforge:forge:1.12.2-14.23.5.2859_mapped_snapshot_20171013-1.12*

The error is with build.gradle in line 0. I didn't change anything inside the file path.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have git installed:

---

### Clone the Minecraft Forge Github repository

```bash
git clone https://github.com/MinecraftForge/MinecraftForge.git
```

---

### Import project into eclipse

1. In eclipse, go to `File --> Import`.
2. In the Import wizard, select "Existing Projects into Workspace" and click Next.
3. In the "**Select root directory**" field, browse to the directory where you cloned the Minecraft Forge repository.
4. Eclipse should automatically detect the Minecraft Forge project. If it does not, you can manually select it by clicking "**Browse**" and navigating to the "**build**" directory within the Minecraft Forge repository.
5. Click "**Finish**" to import the project into Eclipse.

---

### Setting up minecraft

1. Right-click on the Minecraft Forge project in the Package Explorer and select "**Properties**".
2. In the Properties window, go to "Java Build Path" and click on the "**Libraries**" tab.
3. Click on the "**Add External JARs**" button and navigate to the "**lib**" directory within the Minecraft Forge repository.
4. Select all of the JAR files in the "**lib**" directory and click "**Open**".
5. Click "**OK**" to close the Properties window.

---

### Running Minecraft

1. Right-click on the Minecraft Forge project in the Package Explorer and select "`Run As --> Java Application`".

Eclipse will build and run the Minecraft Forge project.

For this guide, I am assuming that you have everything like JDKs configured correctly.